# Does Whatsapp Save Incoming Media feature create duplicates?

Tags: iphone, ios, whatsapp.app

I would like to know if the **Save Incoming Media** feature in Whatsapp ***create duplicates*** i.e. saved in both Whatsapp application data and also Camera roll?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does duplicate media in the sense you describe. With that switch activated, all incoming images will have 2 copies: one on the app and one on the Camera Roll.

Comment: Is there a way to auto delete that data?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your comment, not so much the ability to auto-delete, but switching it off prevents it from being copied to Camera Roll - you'll have to manually delete the message in order to delete the media.